# how to read .doc file windows phone 8 development

Tags: windows-phone-8, .doc

In my windows phone app ,I want to read text from ".doc x" or ".doc".
How can i do that .
User will see a text which is read from .doc or ".doc x" file.

Comment: Assuming you already got the actual file, try [Docx of Codeplex.com](https://docx.codeplex.com/) or Microsoft’s Office interop libraries.

Comment: i actually try to use this code :Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass(); but it gave error on office part says it doesnt recognize office

Comment: We cannot help you with nothing to work on: past the code in your opening post. And describe the problem better: What have you already tried, what is the error, what do you want with the file, is the file already on the device or what?